# How to show image in between display tag library using?

Tags: java, struts2, displaytag

I  am fetching all list of bean object, with I want to display images in between display tag columns from display tag library. How can I do? 
Also I want use Struts tag library in between display tag library. I did this but output not shown.

Comment: Can you give me reason for give negative? - this question is correct if you want to use display tag library that time face the problem. I already solved my problem. If you can't understand the question then you can asked to put the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<display:table export="true" sort="list" id="productTable" name="products" pagesize="3"
                                cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" style="margin-top:20px;">    
<display:column title="Product Image" media="html">
    <img alt="<s:property value="#attr.productTable.productName"/>" src="../uploaded_images/<s:property value="#attr.productTable.productImagesFileName"/>" >
    </display:column>

</display:table>
```